# Cannot find computer in Apple Remote Desktop when using a dock

Tags: dock, remote-desktop

Both systems used for this are running Monterey 12.6. On the target system Remote Management and Remote Login are On with full access set for the local admin user. With the target system connected to the dock I am able to SSH to it with no problem and said system can access local network resources and the Internet. The target system is a MacBook Pro (2021). The dock is a StarTech TB3DK2DPPD ThunderBolt 3 dock.

The issue shows up in Apple Remote Desktop(ARD) on the client system. When a scan is run on the subnet all the other Macs show up as Macs, with a name and blue computer icon, but not the intended target system. The target is found by IP but attempting to connect to it fails.

Oddly when the system is connected to WiFi, same subnet the dock is on, there is no issue with finding and connecting to it. However this is not a valid workaround as WiFi is not available to the user under normal circumstances in the office while a wired connection is.

Any info on this would be helpful.